# Как уменьшить размер изображения в Qt?

Tags: c++, графика, изображения, qt, qimage

Как реализовать программу, которая бы получала на вход изображение, изменяла его, а потом сохраняла новый вариант куда-нибудь в другое место?

Изменить требуется лишь размер. Имеется какой-то `jpeg` или `png` файл с определенным размером, и мне нужно превратить его файл с тем же расширением, но уже с размером 16x32.

Comment: Что говорит мануал Qt? Неужели у них нет штатных средств для Scale изображения?

Answer (score 3):

```
QImage("my-pic.png").scaled(16,32).save("my-pic.png");
```